# tsql put values into single row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, row

this is my issue:

given the result of a select statement that is inserted into a cursor, 
how can I put these values into just one row?

for example given

```
 a
 b
 c
```

how can I achieve a,b,c ?

Comment: Your first question should be "Do I need to use a cursor?"

Answer (score 0):

Insert the results of your cursor into a temp table. The following is for my example but you have to replace it with your cursor.

```
SELECT 'a' AS [Col1]
INTO #Table1

INSERT INTO #Table1
SELECT 'b'
INSERT INTO #Table1
SELECT 'c'
INSERT INTO #Table1
SELECT 'd'
```

Create a dynamic pivot to display the results.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF
            (
               (
                  SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.[Col1]) 
                  FROM   #Table1 c
                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
               ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
               ,1,1,''
            )

SET @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' FROM
             (
                SELECT [Col1]
                FROM   #Table1
             ) x
            PIVOT
            (
                MAX([Col1])
                FOR [Col1] IN(' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


EXECUTE(@query)
```

Drop the temp table

```
DROP TABLE #Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
SUBSTRING((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + [ColumnName] FROM TableName FOR XML PATH('')),2,4000)
```